# HTMLForm's default action

Tags: mediawiki

While doing Code Review on Wikimedia Gerrit, I stumbled across comments saying:

```
$htmlForm->setAction( wfScript() );
```

> Reviewer: not needed, wfScript() is the default for the action.

So I consulted the documentation about [HTMLForm::setAction](https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/master/php/classHTMLForm.html#a24aedd7b2589b5318cb00b26e364ff03) (huge page).

> Set the value for the action attribute of the form.
>   When set to false (which is the default state), the set **title** is used.

However, what I do not understand is how `wfScript` *(Get the path to a specified script file, respecting file extensions; this is a wrapper around $wgScriptPath etc. except for 'index' and 'load' which use $wgScript/$wgLoadScript)* could be **extracted from the title** (instance of [Title](https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/master/php/classTitle.htm)?).

This doesn't make any sense to me as `wfScript()` returns an entry point and all `Title`s usually share the same entry point.

Looking up `HTMLForm::getAction`, I see the code really uses `Title`. Only **conditionally**, though. Simply said, if `Title::getLocalURL` would return a URL containing a query string, e.g. `/mw/index.php?title=Special:Contributions`, `wfScript()` is returned, and the title isn't used at all, as opposed to what is documented in `HTMLForm::setAction()`. The rationale is clear: This is because browsers may strip or amend the query string, which is unwanted here.

**Why isn't the hidden form field approach always used and why does the Title have to know about its entry point?**

**How is `$this->getConfig()->get( 'ArticlePath' )` related to `$this->getTitle()->getLocalURL()`** [The former is used as a condition in and the latter is possibly returned from `HTMLForm::getAction`.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not totally sure I understand your question, so if this answer doesn't really answer your questions, feel free to comment on it and I'll try to fix my answer :)

> Why isn't the hidden form field approach always used and why does the Title have to know about its entry point?

Why should it? It would be possible, yes, but the only reason to use it is, that browsers strip out parameters passed to the `action` parameter of the form. Other values (such as short urls) works fine. The other aspect is, that, if you configure short url's (e.g. yourdomain.com/wiki/Special:UserLogin instead of yourdomain.com/w/index.php?title=Special:UserLogin), why should HTMLForm use
`yourdomain.com/w/index.php?title=Special:UserLogin&wpusername=test&wppassword=123` (bad example, because UserLogin doesn't use HTMLForm and wouldn't use GET, but think about any other example :P) instead of the (for the user) nicer one `yourdomain.com/wiki/Special:UserLogin?wpusername=test&wppassword=123`? So it doesn't have a real technical background to not use always the hidden `title` field, iirc.

> How is $this->getConfig()->get( 'ArticlePath' ) related to $this->getTitle()->getLocalURL()

The [`wgArticlePath`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgArticlePath) configuration variable specifies the base URL for article links, which means, if you call `getLocalURL` on a Title object, the config var is used to build the URL/Link if no query is specified (see the code of [getLocalURL](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgArticlePath) to know how it works). That means, that the config variable specifies, how links are returned from this function (e.g. /w/index.php?title=$1 or /wiki/$1). So it's a very important part for this function and (to close the circle to HTMLForm) the important condition to decide, if wfScript() is used or the local url (from the Title object), as it is the condition for Title::getLocalURL() to decide if a question mark is used or not.

I hope that helps a bit to understand what HTMLForm does, if not, feel free to comment :)

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive response. Okay, one part is clear now. The one that isn't: `Title::getLocalURL()` basically does `$url = str_replace( '$1', $dbkey, $wgArticlePath );` when invoked without $query. Is it because this replace operation or the hooks are expensive or for consistency with `HTMLForm::getHiddenFields()` that first a config variable is fetched, analysed, and `Title::getLocalURL()` is called only conditionally, while one could call it immediately and search the result for the question mark without looking at the config?

Comment: I'm not sure, if it's maded in this way because of performance reasons, but it would make sense. The title can be local only (at least it should for a HTMLForm), and it should always be called without any query, so the only condition to consider is the config variable. I think it was the easiest way in the time when this was implemented :)